# WatiN generates empty pages

Tags: c#, nunit, watin

When capturing images using WatiN the resulting images are just empty, solid black. The size of the images equals the screen size, though. For example the following snippet just saves two black images.

```
using (IE ie = new IE()) {
            ie.ClearCache();
            ie.BringToFront();
            ie.GoTo("http://localhost/");
            ie.CaptureWebPageToFile(imageDir + "\\localhost.png");
            WatiN.Core.CaptureWebPage capture = new CaptureWebPage(ie);
            capture.CaptureWebPageToFile(imageDir + "\\localhost.jpg", true, true, 100, 80);
            Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("Zend"));
        }
```

Other have reported this as well but I haven't seen any solution. See comments here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/IECapture.aspx?display=PrintAll&fid=192174&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=51&select=1810490

Hope any can shed some light on this.

Cheers
// John

Comment: Which version of IE and WatiN are you using?

Comment: Hi!

I've tried both IE 7 (7.0.5730.13) on Win2003 Server and IE 8 (8.06001.18702) on WinXP. I've tried setting the comaptibility mode in IE8 as well, without success. The most frustraing thing is that when I made some screenshots two months ago it worked perfectly. But then I used IE7. 

Watin is version WatiN 1.3.0.4000. I've tried both the binary version and self-compiled (as just the jpg image format worked in the binary).

The screenshots are made as part of nunit tests, run by nant.

Thanks for your concern!
// John

Comment: Hi Jon, the upcoming WatiN 2.0 beta 2 has a fix for capturing IE8 screenshot. The issue with jpg being the only image format that works is fixed in beta 1. HTH, Jeroen

Comment: I fixed the jpg problem myself by correcting a typo in the sourcecode for version 1.3.0.4000 and then compiling watin. Neither the binary or the selfcompiled version works. 

Anyway it doesn't seem to be that IE necessarily is the problem as it doesn't work in IE7.

As version 2.0 is beta2 I might consider that instead. Then I get support for Firefox :-)



// John

Comment: Just want to share with you that I changed to Watin 2.0 beta 1 and the images continue to be black on the test platsforms mentioned above.

// John

Comment: It's already 6 month since last post and beta2 is still not out. Anybody knows when will it happen?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get it working for my web pages under IE8 with the following changes:

Replace the following method:

```
private static IntPtr GetHwndForInternetExplorerServer(IntPtr hwnd)
{
    var sbc = new StringBuilder(256);
    hwnd = NativeMethods.GetWindow(hwnd, NativeMethods.GW_CHILD);
    while (hwnd != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        NativeMethods.GetClassName(hwnd, sbc, 256);
        if (sbc.ToString().IndexOf("Shell DocObject View", 0) > -1) //IE6
        {
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", IntPtr.Zero);
            break;
        }
        if (sbc.ToString().IndexOf("TabWindowClass", 0) > -1) //IE7
        {
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", IntPtr.Zero);
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", IntPtr.Zero);
            break;
        }
        if (sbc.ToString().IndexOf("Frame Tab", 0) > -1) // IE8
        {
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "TabWindowClass", IntPtr.Zero);
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Shell DocObject View", IntPtr.Zero);
            hwnd = NativeMethods.FindWindowEx(hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, "Internet Explorer_Server", IntPtr.Zero);
            break;
        }
        hwnd = NativeMethods.GetWindow(hwnd, NativeMethods.GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
    return hwnd;
}
```

Remove the method GetHwndContainingAShellDocObjectView and the call to it.